# Selenium - SendKeys("@") write an "à"

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm starting to use Selenium to test my website, but when i'm testing it on Internet Explorer, the function SendKeys("@") write "à" instead of "@".

Otherwise, it's working well on Chrome and FF.

If you have the answer........... :)

Here is my code:

```
        IWebElement loginInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login-inputEl"));
        loginInput.SendKeys("test@test.fr");
```

Ty!

Comment: On my US keyboard, the "@" is shift+2. What is there on yours? (I don't know whether that is the issue, just a wild guess)

Comment: Does it work if you do `loginInput.SendKeys("\u0040")` instead?

Comment: Hi, it's writing 'à' as before... nice try, ty

Comment: Are you using a non-english keyboard? Also is the site a non-english site?

Comment: I'm using a french keyboard, and the site is in french too

Comment: I have the same issue, if you find the answer please answer it to you same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, in order to write an "@" with selenium in IE Driver!
With a french keyboard, you need to press the  graph key "ALT GR" and the key "à" to get an "@", then, you'll need to tell Selenium to do the same action.

```
loginInput.SendKeys("test"); // the beginning of my email adress
var actions = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(driver);
actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.LeftAlt); // I press my graph key "ALT GR"
actions.SendKeys("à"); // Then, my key "@"
actions.KeyUp(Keys.Control).KeyUp(Keys.LeftAlt); // I release my key
actions.Build().Perform(); // execute
loginInput.SendKeys("test.fr"); // the end of my email adress
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
loginInput.SendKeys(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("test@test.fr"));
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a couple of days with this same problem, I've found a solution, which is practical and will allow us to enter an email address containing the @ with no hassle.

> str email = "username@domain.com";
>   Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Name("username")).SendKeys(email);

This should resolve the problem. I was trying to enter the email as var, and was always entering the **@** symbols as a **q** (I have spanish lat kb) and well... str did a good job.

I hope you can use this tip for your Tests!

Ciao.

Comment: What's str? This is a C# question so something else than string?

Answer (score 0):

In Java I solved converting the input string in a List of Characters and comparing it with the specials characters.

```
static String charsSpecial = "@#[]€";
```

my method is this.

```
public static void insertValueExplorer(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait mywait, String locator, String variable) {
        mywait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(locator))).clear();   
        if(driver.toString().contains("InternetExplorerDriver")){
            List<Character> chars = Utils.convertStringToCharList(variable);
            int j=0;
            while(j<chars.size())
            { 
                if (charsSpecial.contains(chars.get(j).toString())){
                
                    mywait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(locator))).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ALT, chars.get(j).toString())); 
                }else{
                    mywait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(locator))).sendKeys(chars.get(j).toString()); 
                }
                j=j+1;
            }
        }else {
            mywait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(locator))).sendKeys(variable);    
        }
    }
```

I execute my tests on all browsers but this method is necessary only for Explorer